# C# App hangs during failed SqlConnection

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, freeze, sqlconnection

I am building an C# app that connects to SQL Server and a database. On my network the PC that is running the server has a reserved IP on my router. So, this is the part of the code that hangs if SQLConnection fails. Here the code:

```
public static Boolean RevisarEstado(String ip, String usuario, String pass)
    {

        Boolean estado = false;
        SqlConnection miconexion = new SqlConnection("Data source=" + ip + ";DataBase=Final_Algoritmos;User ID=" + usuario + ";Password=" + pass);

        try
        {
            miconexion.Open();
            estado = true;
            miconexion.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception) { estado = false;  miconexion.Close(); }
        return estado;

    }
```

if the parameters of SqlConnection are Ok, the app does not hangs, but if are not correct, the app hags. I am programming with windows form C#.

I think that I must use Threads during the process of checking the connection, using a status bar while the connection fails. So. Help me! Please!

Comment: Have you tried setting the connection timeout in the connection string? e.g. `;Connection Timeout=10;` where 10 is in seconds.

Comment: If you want to test the connection on a secondary thread then go ahead and do it.  If you actually have issues when doing it, that would be the time to post a question here.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Loathing , I tried but It hangs more than 10 seconds

Comment: I think doing in a second thread, using the OpenAsync method, but I do not know how to use it

Comment: Not related to your problem but you might want to look in to the [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) class, it is much more reliable than using string concatination. For example, what if a user wants to have a `;` in their password? The connection string builder automatically handles the escaping of the semicolon;

Comment: Scott thanks for this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check your connection, try creating a new [thread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740(v=vs.71).aspx) to do:

```
//Put these two lines to where you want to check the connection
Thread checkConnection = new Thread(() => checkConn());
checkConnection.Start();

//Then create a method like below
public void checkConn()
{
     //Call the check connection method here
     if(!miconexion(ip, user, pass))
     {
         //Handle failure here, please use Invoke if you want to control the UI thread.
     }
     //For best resource usage, join the thread after using it.
     Thead.Join();
}
```

Then your program won't hangs.

Comment: Ty @User2012384 but I have just on little error Thread.Join(); show a error about non-static field, methods or property

Comment: How about Thread.CurrentThread.Join()? I don't have a compiler on hand. give it a try

Comment: Yes, It worked, No i must work about the Invoke. The situation with hangs has stopped, but the handle failure reacts before 54 seconds after app startup. One last thing more... Thread checkConnection = new Thread(() => checkConn());  The thread parameter is like this. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Oh, thanks for the correction, if you come across any problems, please feel free to ask.